How is the derivative with respect to $x$, $y$, $z$ found of $F(x,y,z) = x^2 y + x^2 x^3 + y^4$?
How is the derivative with respect to $x$,$y$,$z$ found of $F(x,y,z) = x^2 y + x^2 x^3 + y^4?$

Do you know how partial derivatives are computed? The definition gives you motivation.

My intention in saying this is not to be condescending, but have you checked Khan Academy? I am almost certain they have a video covering problems such as these.

$\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,y,z) = \lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{F(x+h,y,z)-F(x,y,z)}{h}$
$\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y}(x,y,z) = \lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{F(x,y+h,z)-F(x,y,z)}{h}$
$\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y}(x,y,z) = \lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{F(x,y,z+h)-F(x,y,z)}{h}$
